# FIFO on inventory stocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns all the available stocks on the database. I
need to make a stored procedure to get the itemCode, batchNo, quantity, price of specific item that the users entered.

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | itemCode | batchNo | availQty | price |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | item_1   | 07292016|   5      |  5.50 |
| 2  | item_1   | 07312016|   10     |  5.50 |
| 3  | item_1   | 08012016|   2      |  6.00 |
```

My problem is that, if the users entered 6 quantity to be purchased, how can I get the first 2 lines of result to get the total quantity of 6?

Result must be:

```
07292016  --- 5
07312016  --- 1
```

Comment: Post your query for more clarification

Comment: Tag the question with your sql server version. If it supports SUM OVER() solution is simple.

Comment: @jarlh, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @KarthickRajan, sir the query is too long, but lets assume that the output of the table or the values in the table is just like what i've posted,

Comment: @serg, sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is efficient and the query is horid, but the following will give you what you want:

```
-- Create Test Data
create table #Items
(
    id int not null primary key,
    itemCode varchar(30) not null,
    batchNumber varchar(30) not null,
    availQty int not null,
    price smallmoney not null
);

insert into #Items
values
    (1, 'item_1', '07292016', 5, 5.50),
    (2, 'item_1', '07312016', 10, 5.50),
    (3, 'item_1', '08012016', 2, 6.00)

select 
    *
from
    #Items
;

-- Set up required parameters
declare 
    @requiredItemCode varchar(30) = 'item_1',
    @requiredQty int = 6

-- The query to get the required result
select
    i.*,
    case
        when
            @requiredQty - 
            isnull(
                (
                    select
                        sum(availQty)
                    from
                        #Items i2
                    where
                        i2.itemCode = i.itemCode
                        and i2.id < i.Id
                ),
                0) < i.availQty
        then
            @requiredQty - 
            isnull(
                (
                    select
                        sum(availQty)
                    from
                        #Items i2
                    where
                        i2.itemCode = i.itemCode
                        and i2.id < i.Id
                ),
                0)
        else
            i.availQty
    end as qtyToTake
from 
    #Items i
where   
    i.ItemCode = @requiredItemCode
    and 
    case
        when
            @requiredQty - 
            isnull(
                (
                    select
                        sum(availQty)
                    from
                        #Items i2
                    where
                        i2.itemCode = i.itemCode
                        and i2.id < i.Id
                ),
                0) < i.availQty
        then
            @requiredQty - 
            isnull(
                (
                    select
                        sum(availQty)
                    from
                        #Items i2
                    where
                        i2.itemCode = i.itemCode
                        and i2.id < i.Id
                ),
                0)
        else
            i.availQty
    end > 0

-- Clean up test data
drop table #Items
```

Output:

```
id          itemCode batchNumber availQty    price
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           item_1   07292016    5           5.50
2           item_1   07312016    10          5.50
3           item_1   08012016    2           6.00

(3 row(s) affected)

id          itemCode batchNumber availQty    price                 qtyToTake
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- --------------------- -----------
1           item_1   07292016    5           5.50                  5
2           item_1   07312016    10          5.50                  1

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: sir can you enlighten me about the query in the line 
" and i2.id < i.Id " ?
how important that line is ? 
thank you.

Comment: The reason for the "and i2.id < i.Id" clause is to ensure that the sub query only sums up the values for the rows with an id less than the row it is currently working on. Without this it would sum all the rows and get the wrong result. It also sets the order in which the results are obtained. If you swap it for i2.Id > i.Id you would get rows with ids 2 and 3 instead of rows 1 and 2.

Comment: is there other way that we can achieved the output without using the id ? because i'm thinking that, the value of id might not be ordered by asc.

Comment: You can replace the Id by which ever column your data is orderd on. Batch number might work but it is hard to know without more information about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (id INT, itemCode NVARCHAR(50), batchNo NVARCHAR(50), availQty INT, price DECIMAL(5,2))

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES        
(1, 'item_1'   , '07292016',   5      ,  5.50 ),
( 2  , 'item_1',    '07312016'   ,10,  5.50),
( 3  , 'item_1',    '08012016'   ,2 ,  6.00 )


DECLARE @Quantity INT = 6

SELECT * 
FROM
    @Tbl
WHERE
    id <= (
            SELECT TOP 1
                  A.id
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    id ,
                    itemCode ,
                    batchNo ,
                    availQty ,
                    price,
                    (SELECT SUM(availQty) FROM @Tbl IT WHERE IT.id <= T.id)  AS TotalAmount
                FROM
                    @Tbl T
            ) A
            WHERE
                A.TotalAmount >= @Quantity
            ORDER BY A.id
          )
```

Output:

```
id  itemCode    batchNo     availQty    price
1   item_1      07292016    5           5.50
2   item_1      07312016    10          5.50
```

UPDATED

```
SELECT
    R.id ,
    R.itemCode ,
    R.batchNo ,
    R.availQty ,
    R.price ,
    CASE WHEN R.MaxId = id THEN R.availQty - (TotalQuantity - @Quantity)
        ELSE R.availQty END OutQuantity
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id ,
        itemCode ,
        batchNo ,
        availQty ,
        price,
        MAX(id) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) MaxId,
        SUM(availQty) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) TotalQuantity
    FROM
        @Tbl
    WHERE
        id <= (
                SELECT TOP 1
                      A.id
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        id ,
                        itemCode ,
                        batchNo ,
                        availQty ,
                        price,
                        (SELECT SUM(availQty) FROM @Tbl IT WHERE IT.id <= T.id)  AS TotalAmount
                    FROM
                        @Tbl T
                ) A
                WHERE
                    A.TotalAmount >= @Quantity
                ORDER BY A.id
              )
) R
WHERE 
  @Quantity > 0
```

Output

```
id  itemCode    batchNo     availQty    price   OutQuantity
1   item_1      07292016    5           5.50    5
2   item_1      07312016    10          5.50    1
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but can you give an idea how to get only 1 quantity in then line 2 ? thanks

Comment: For reference the SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...) is not supported in versions of SQL Server older than 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but still you may do change on top of this if you have any issues. Hope you wanted this

```
  CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getStock @item_Code nvarchar(30), @quantity  int
    AS 
    //Declare variables
    DECLARE @id INT
    DECLARE @itemCode nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @batchNo nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @qty INT
    DECLARE @cumulativeQty INT
    DECLARE @price DECIMAL(18,2)

    //Declare cursor
    DECLARE @getStock CURSOR
    SET @getStock = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id, ItemCode, batchNo, availQty, price
    FROM your_table
    WHERE ItemCode = @item_Code
    ORDER BY  batchNo ASC

    //Create temp table to store all of the intermediate stock records into it

    //If always make sure if its already exist just drop and recreate



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TmpStock') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TmpStock
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #TmpStock(Id INT, ItemCode nvarchar(30), BatchNo nvarchar(30), Quatnity INT, Price Decimal(18,2))
    END


    //Open the cursor
    OPEN @getStudents 

    //Read the next row record into the cursor
    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM @getStock INTO @id, @itmCode, @batchNo, @qty, @price


    SET @cumulativeQty = 0

    //Loop through one row by another which is selected above and stored in cursor

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    //If the cumulative quantity is less than user's input quantity 
    //then keep inserting into the temp table and deduct the inserted qty
    SET @cumulativeQty  = @cumulativeQty + @qty

    IF( @quantity <= @cumulativeQty)
        INSERT INTO #TmpStock VALUES(@id, @itmCode, @batchNo, @quantity, @price );
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO #TmpStock VALUES(@id, @itmCode, @batchNo, @qty, @price );
    @cumulativeQty= @quantity - @qty
    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getStock INTO @id, @itmCode, @batchNo, @qty, @price
    END


    //Closing the cursor
    CLOSE @getStock
    DEALLOCATE @getStock

//Now select your data from temp table
SELECT * FROM #TmpStock
```